# How can I understand if I have installed react native or not?

Tags: react-native

ı installed node js and npm.
i installed react native https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup with this link

```
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/mac/.npm/_logs/2020-08-29T06_28_37_573Z-debug.log
mac-macbook-air:~ mac$
```

Comment: ```sudo npm install``` and enter your domain password

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm throws error without sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo)

Comment: i entered sudo npm install 
and enter my password i get this 
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mac/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/mac/package.json'
npm WARN mac No description
npm WARN mac No repository field.
npm WARN mac No README data
npm WARN mac No license field.

up to date in 1.315s
found 0 vulnerabilities

Comment: This package has installed:
 • Node.js v12.18.3 to /usr/local/bin/node
 • npm v6.14.6 to /usr/local/bin/npm
Make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $PATH.

Comment: ı installed again